# jquery css selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get the window's width & height + a div's width & height to find the adjusted width.  I'm also trying to absolutely position the div with jquery, but my code isn't working.  I'll provide the code below.

**CSS:**

```
#inner {
  width: 500px; height: 300px;
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var screenWidth = $(window).width();
  var screenHeight = $(window).height();

  var boxWidth = $("#inner").width();
  var boxHeight = $("#inner").height();

  var adjustedWidth = screenWidth - boxWidth;
  var adjustedHeight = screenHeight - boxHeight;

  $("#inner").css('position', 'absolute');
  $("#inner").css('top', adjustedWidth + 'px');
  $("#inner").css('left', adjustedHeight + 'px');

});
```

What am I doing wrong in my jQuery?  Hopefully I've been clear in my explanations.

Comment: What does "my code isn't working" mean? Do you get an error? Do you not get the result you expect? What do you get and what do you expect?  Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: can you post the associated HTML in case it plays a part in the problem?

Comment: Tried a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gnvaG/ and it seems to work fine (check the source of the result). You're probably not including the jQuery correctly, or your HTML is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to align your div at the very bottom right, then you've mixed up top -> adjustedWidth and left -> adjustedHeight:

```
$("#inner").css('top', adjustedWidth + 'px');
$("#inner").css('left', adjustedHeight + 'px');
```

when it should be the other way around:

```
$("#inner").css('top', adjustedHeight + 'px');
$("#inner").css('left', adjustedWidth + 'px');
```

Apart from that, your code [looks like it works](http://jsfiddle.net/apKPP/).

Also, you don't need to add "px" when trying to change the CSS width or height.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use JavaScript for this. When absolutely positioning things, `left` and `top` are not the only things you can use; instead, you can use `right` and `bottom` where appropriate. For example, to position something in the bottom right corner as you appear to be doing, you could use this:

```css
#something {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    background: red;
}
```

**[Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/2EG5Z/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you code includes getting size of a component (especially there is image on the page), you want to put the code in `load` handler rather than `ready` handler, because `ready` is executed before all images are downloaded and the size of the page could vary after that.

Also your `top` and `left` should be exchanged.

```
$(document).on('load', function() {

  var screenWidth = $(window).width();
  var screenHeight = $(window).height();

  var boxWidth = $("#inner").width();
  var boxHeight = $("#inner").height();

  var adjustedWidth = screenWidth - boxWidth;
  var adjustedHeight = screenHeight - boxHeight;

  $("#inner").css('position', 'absolute');
  $("#inner").css('top', adjustedHeight + 'px');
  $("#inner").css('left', adjustedWidth + 'px');

});
```